# Theme Drupal Form API checkboxes as a grid

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I have a custom form that displays a form element of about 2 dozen checkboxes. I would like to output them 3 per row, in a table if possible. How can I go about doing that?

```
$form['preference'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#default_value' => 1373,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => 'Choose all that apply',
    '#options' => $preference_options,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="preference-options">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

Comment: Not sure what it is that you're asking. What you've done seems correct. Are you talking about how you style them so that each group sits on it's own line? If so this is more of a CSS question and not a Drupal one.

Comment: Drupal is outputting a div with a label and input inside of it. It would make more sense to have a table for a grid because the CSS can be tricky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, define a custom theme function with hook_theme() and assign it to the form element with #theme.

In that theme function, you can use [expand_checkboxes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/expand_checkboxes/6) to convert it into an array of separate checkbox elements. Then, re-structure it into an array with 3 elements each, render the checkboxes and pass it to theme_table().

Something like this, all untested.

```
function theme_yourmodule_preference($element) {
  $elements = element_children(expand_checkboxes($element));

  $rows = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i += 3) {
    $row = array(drupal_render($elements[$i]));
    // The following two might not always exist, check first.
    if (isset($elements[$i + 1]) {
      $row[] = drupal_render($elements[$i + 1]);
    }
    if (isset($elements[$i + 2]) {
      $row[] = drupal_render($elements[$i + 2]);
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
  return theme('table', array(), $rows);
}
```

Comment: I needed to use `return theme('table', array('rows' =>$rows));` - are you sure your code is OK?

Answer (score 4):

I adapted Berdir's solution for display in columns and Drupal 7. Thought I'd share it.

```
function yourmodule_theme() {
  return array
      (
      'form_yourmodule_form' => array
          (
          'render element' => 'form'
      ),
  );
}

function theme_form_yourmodule_form($variables) {

  $form = $variables['form'];

  $element = $form['checkboxelement'];
  unset($form['checkboxelement']);

  $elements = element_children(form_process_checkboxes($element));

  $colnr = 3;   // set nr of columns here

  $itemCount = count($elements);
  $rowCount = $itemCount / $colnr;
  if (!is_int($rowCount))
    $rowCount = round((($itemCount / $colnr) + 0.5), 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
  $rows = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
    $row = array();
    for ($col = 0; $col < $colnr; $col++) {
      if (isset($elements[$i + $rowCount * $col]))
        $row[] = drupal_render($element[$elements[$i + $rowCount * $col]]);
    }
    $rows[] = $row;
  }

  $variable = array(
      'header' => array(),
      'rows' => $rows,
      'attributes' => array('class' => 'checkbox_columns'),
      'caption' => NULL,
      'colgroups' => NULL,
      'sticky' => NULL,
      'empty' => NULL,
  );


  $output = theme_table($variable);

  $output .= drupal_render_children($form);

  return $output;
}
```

I found an even easier solution: there is a module for this!
[Multi-column checkboxes radios](http://drupal.org/project/multicolumncheckboxesradios)