# Rendering a simple PHP array into an HTML table

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to render a simple PHP array witch isn't a drupal render array, basicly it s something like this:

```
array(
  array(
    'Some Index:',
    ' Some value',
  ),
  array(
    'Some Index:',
    'Some value',
  )
);
```

I would like to render it as an HTML table, is there any out of the box API to do that ?

Thank all for the help,

Cheers

Comment: Please, look at [`theme_table()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/7). For example this [answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/389/theme-drupal-form-api-checkboxes-as-a-grid).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you have code similar to this:

```
$table_data = array(
  array( 'Some Index', 'Some value'),
  array( 'Some Index', 'Some value'),
);
```

In this case, just call `theme('table', array('header' => array(), 'rows' => $table_data));`.

This will call [`theme_table()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_table/7), unless your theme overrides that particular theming function. Any override, however, should expect the array to be structured in the same way as described for `theme_table()`, so look there about the specifics. In particular, you might want to replace `'Some Index'` with `array('data' => 'Some Index', 'header' => TRUE)` to indicate that this cell is a table header cell.