# Create a tableselect like /admin/people/permissions

Tags: theming, forms

I want to create a table that looks like the drupal table on : /admin/people/permissions (table with multiple checkboxes on every line)

Any help is welecome

Comment: do you want exactly the same page? I mean do you want to work with permissions or you just want to work with check boxes?(based on your other questions)

Comment: Hi, no not the same page(permissions), i want to work with check boxes

Comment: At some point you might have to concede that you just can't do this with a tableselect, bite the bullet, and theme the form elements into a table yourself (e.g. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/389/theme-drupal-form-api-checkboxes-as-a-grid)

Comment: Hi Clive, I think I'm on the right way (thank you) I've just only one problem, and I think you can help me

Comment: I found a link that show how to theme a table with a list (first column) and checkboxes (second one), we can add more columns if we want, so it seems to be good for me, the problem is that in this example, he worked with checkboxes and i need to use only checkbox per column(i don't need options) here is the link (see 2nd way)https://www.drupal.org/node/1393626#comment-10132722 PLEASE check it Clive I'm working on it for 2 days and It's not working

Comment: What works for me : first column ( a list of terms from taxonomy_term_data, it shows me all my terms). what doesn't work : a second column that supposed to be a column of checkbox (i have an empty column, and only one checkbox out of the table) this checkbox must be on the second column and on every line (next to every term i need to see a checkbox in the second column)